# Can I set the index column when reading a CSV using Python dask?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dask

When using Python Pandas to read a CSV it is possible to specify the index column. Is this possible using Python Dask when reading the file, as opposed to setting the index afterwards?

For example, using pandas:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
```

Ideally using dask could this be:

```
df = dask.dataframe.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
```

I have tried

```
df = dask.dataframe.read_csv(filename).set_index(?)
```

but the index column does not have a name (and this seems slow).

Comment: the documentation seems to indicate that `df = dask.dataframe.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)` should work as the `kwargs` are passed to `pandas`, did you try this?

Comment: I did try and it failed with the error highlighted by MRocklin below, i.e. `ValueError: Keyword 'index' not supported dd.read_csv(...).set_index('my-index') instead`

Answer (score 8):

No, these need to be two separate methods.  If you try this then Dask will tell you in a nice error message.

```
In [1]: import dask.dataframe as dd
In [2]: df = dd.read_csv('*.csv', index='my-index')
ValueError: Keyword 'index' not supported dd.read_csv(...).set_index('my-index') instead
```

But this won't be any slower or faster than doing it the other way.

Comment: won't this be much slower on partitioned data? if each csv is a partition on the index, nothing would need to be run, however, set_index would force a full execution on the entire dataset just to build the index's meta data.

Comment: If you know the partitions ahead of time then you can specify them in the `set_index` call.  If you don't know them then we'll have to read the files anyway.  If they are already sorted then Dask will do this in a single read.

Comment: @MRocklin Is there an option for continous `time series` in csv files to let `dask` before the read that these are already `sorted timestamps`? That would allow it to dask to get the first and last row of the csv, knowing the time ranges for the partitions before their creation . Would that help preventing shuffling during the `set_index` method?

Comment: [Ok just reading through..](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index), the answer is `ddf.set_index('col', sorted=True)`. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late, but this is the first result on google so it should get answered.

If you write your dataframe with:

```
# index = True is default
my_pandas_df.to_csv('path')

#so this is same
my_pandas_df.to_csv('path', index=True)
```

And import with Dask:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
my_dask_df = dd.read_csv('path').set_index('Unnamed: 0')
```

It will use column 0 as your index (which is unnamed thanks to pandas.DataFrame.to_csv() ).

### How to figure it out:

```
my_dask_df = dd.read_csv('path')
my_dask_df.columns
```

which returns

```
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'col 0', 'col 1',
       ...
       'col n'],
      dtype='object', length=...)
```

Comment: This gives `KeyError: 'Unnamed: 0'`

Answer (score 2):

Now you can write: `df = pandas.read_csv(filename, index_col='column_name')` (Where column name is the name of the column you want to set as the index).